# Histogram of a value for a variable over unique values of another variable

Tags: histogram, stata

I have a dataset in Stata with 203 rows and 2 columns. Here is some rows:

```
Voting Bidvalue 
  0       720
  1       15
  0       120
  0       960
  1       30
  1       400
  0       60
  0       960
  0       240
```

There are eight different bid values including 15, 30, 60, 120, 240, 360, 480, 720. For each bid value, we can find the number of 1 and 0 for the Voting column. Here is the screenshot of the detailed information.

[image]

I want to find a histogram that the x-axis is 8 bid values and the y-axis is the number of 1 for the Voting column.

Comment: Please provide example data via a code listing, not a screenshot. See the Stata tag wiki and look at `help dataex` (if necessary, `ssc install dataex` first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
histogram Bidvalue if Voting == 1 , freq
```

is an answer to the question. It is perhaps more likely that you want something more like

```
egen Toshow = group(Bidvalue), label 
label var Toshow "Bidvalue" 
histogram Toshow if Voting == 1, xla(1/8, valuelabel) discrete freq
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick! The code works for me, especially the label looks great.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

`graph bar (count) Voting, over(Bidvalue)`